# new XMLHttpRequest in joomla 3

Tags: ajax

I have created a module from https://github.com/Joomla-Ajax-Interface/Ajax-Session-Module (Ajax-Session-Module) loaded it to my site and yes it does what the example showed: Added a value, deleted a value and deletes all values.

How do I leverage this module to make a request inside Joomla. I know this code works fine outside of Joomla.

```
        //AJAX - Creates the XMLHttpRequest that sends a http request to the web server
    function getXMLHTTP() {
        var x = false;
        try {
            x = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch(e) {
            try {
                x = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(ex) {
                try {
                    req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(e1) {
                    x = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return x;
    }

    //AJAX - Retrieves the teams based on the division choice
    function leagueABCD(strURL) {         
         var rer = getXMLHTTP(); 
         if (rer) {
          rer.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (rer.readyState == 4) { 
           if (rer.status == 200) {                   
             document.getElementById("homeTeam").innerHTML=rer.responseText;
             <!--alert(rer.responseText);-->
          }
          else { 
             alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n");
          }
         }            
        }        
        rer.open("GET", strURL, true); 
        rer.send(null);
       }
    }

    //AJAX - Retrieves the players based on the home team choice
    function homeTeam(strURL) {         
         var req = getXMLHTTP(); 
         if (req) {
          req.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (req.readyState == 4) { 
           if (req.status == 200) {                   
             document.getElementById("playersHomeTeam").innerHTML=req.responseText;
             <!--alert(req.responseText);-->
          }
          else { 
             alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n");
          }
         }            
        }        
        req.open("GET", strURL, true); 
        req.send(null);
       }
    }

    //AJAX - Retrieves the players based on the visiting team choice
    function visitingTeam(strURL) {         
         var vt = getXMLHTTP(); 
         if (vt) {
          vt.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (vt.readyState == 4) { 
           if (vt.status == 200) {                   
             document.getElementById("playersVisitingTeam").innerHTML=vt.responseText;
             <!--alert(vt.responseText);-->
          }
          else { 
             alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n");
          }
         }            
        }        
        vt.open("GET", strURL, true); 
        vt.send(null);
       }
    }

    //AJAX - Retrieves the current rating based on the player choice
    function idP(strURL) {         
         var rer = getXMLHTTP(); 
         if (rer) {
          rer.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (rer.readyState == 4) { 
           if (rer.status == 200) {                   
             document.getElementById("ratingC").innerHTML=rer.responseText;
             <!--alert(rer.responseText);-->
          }
          else { 
             alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n");
          }
         }            
        }        
        rer.open("GET", strURL, true); 
        rer.send(null);
       }
    }
```

In the default.php file is where the 'mini form' is being generated from.
Any help would be awesome.

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: Apparently my issue was here in the form...                            <select class="select" id="leagueChoice" name="league" onchange="leagueABCD('/includes/ewms/findleague.php?league='+this.value);">    I had to add two folders to the findleague.php path!  (just in case anyone else forgets to do that !)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my issue was here in the form...  I had to add two folders to the findleague.php path! (just in case anyone else forgets to do that !)